# Unable to retrieve dynamic control generated from db - POST values (Model Binding)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, controller, viewmodel, modelbinders

I have been developing an ASP.NET MVC page where I need to bring the controls from database, so in database I have created our control details like name, value, id.

The one way GET path is done, now in POST I find amazing that I am not able to get the `IEnumerable<MyControls>` with the help of model binder, hope it would be nice learning for me If someone tell me whats wrong or some thing architecturally I am missing out pls help me with my piece of this work.

**Model**

```
public class QuestionaireControlMasterModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Questiono { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string ControlType { get; set; }
    public string ControlDescription { get; set; }
    public string ControlName { get; set; }

    // My question from Question table   //
    public string ControlLabel { get; set; }
    public string ControlId { get; set; }
    public string ControlValue { get; set; }
    public string IsChecked { get; set; }

    // for ddl list//
    public List<string> ddlhtmllistppt { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class ControlViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<QuestionaireControlMasterModel> ListofControls { get; set; }
}
```

**Database**:

```
create table ControlMaster
(
    ControlType int identity primary key,
    ControlDescription nvarchar(500)
)

create table Questionaire
(
    Questiono int identity(1,1) primary key,
    Question nvarchar(500),
)

create table QuestionaireControlMaster
(
    Id int identity (1,1) primary key,
    Questiono int
        Constraint fk_QuestionaireControlMaster_Questiono 
             references Questionaire(Questiono),
    ControlType int 
        Constraint fk_QuestionaireControlMaster_ControlType 
             references ControlMaster(ControlType),

    // Control Name I use in View //
    ControlName1 nvarchar(500),

    // Control Id I use in View //
    ControlId1 nvarchar(500),

    IsChecked1 nvarchar(500),
)

create table ValueMaster
(
    ValueID int identity(1,1) primary key,
    ControlValue nvarchar(500),
    Id int
        Constraint fk_ValueMaster_Id 
            references QuestionaireControlMaster(Id),
)
```

**Controller**

```
     public ActionResult Index()
            {

                // View Model Object//
                ControlViewModel controlviewmodel = new ControlViewModel();

                using (var db = new OfficialEntities())
                {
                    // Retrieval of data from QuestionMaster table

                    var retrievedlistfromdb = db.QuestionaireControlMasters.ToList();

                    //Creating a list of Questionaire table Model to store the list of controls needed//

                    List<QuestionaireControlMasterModel> listofquestionmodel = new List<QuestionaireControlMasterModel>();

                    // Storing the retrieved list of controls from db to our list in ViewModel //

// Mapping retrieved list from db to my list of controls //

                    foreach (var temp in retrievedlistfromdb)
                    {

                        QuestionaireControlMasterModel questionaireControlMasterModel = new QuestionaireControlMasterModel();
                        List<string> testinglist = new List<string>();
                        questionaireControlMasterModel.ControlType = temp.ControlMaster.ControlDescription;

                        if (questionaireControlMasterModel.ControlType == "checkbox")
                        {
                            questionaireControlMasterModel.ControlLabel = temp.Questionaire.Question;
                            questionaireControlMasterModel.ControlId = temp.ControlId1;
                            questionaireControlMasterModel.ControlName = temp.ControlName1;


                            using (var dbconnectovalues = new OfficialEntities())
                            {
                                var values = dbconnectovalues.ValueMasters.Where(x => x.Id == temp.Id).ToList();

                                if (values.Count == 1)
                                {
                                    foreach (var item in values)
                                    {

                                        questionaireControlMasterModel.ControlValue = item.ControlValue;
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                            questionaireControlMasterModel.IsChecked = temp.IsChecked1;

                            questionaireControlMasterModel.ddlhtmllistppt = testinglist;
                            listofquestionmodel.Add(questionaireControlMasterModel);
                        }
    // For Dropdownlist and textbox separate mapping //

                        else
                        {
                            questionaireControlMasterModel.ControlLabel = temp.Questionaire.Question;
                            questionaireControlMasterModel.ControlId = temp.ControlId1;
                            questionaireControlMasterModel.ControlName = temp.ControlName1;

                            using (var dbconnectovalues = new OfficialEntities())
                            {
                                var values = dbconnectovalues.ValueMasters.Where(x => x.Id == temp.Id).ToList();

                                if (values.Count == 1)
                                {
                                    foreach (var item in values)
                                    {

                                        questionaireControlMasterModel.ControlValue = item.ControlValue;
                                    }
                                }

                                if (values.Count > 1)
                                {

                                    foreach (var item in values)
                                    {

                                        string tempvar = item.ControlValue;

                                        testinglist.Add(tempvar);

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            questionaireControlMasterModel.IsChecked = temp.IsChecked1;
                            questionaireControlMasterModel.ddlhtmllistppt = testinglist;
                            listofquestionmodel.Add(questionaireControlMasterModel);
                        }


                        // Attaching my List to the lIst property of the View Model//

                        controlviewmodel.ListofControls = listofquestionmodel;

                    }

                    //Passing ViewModel Object which contains the list of controls of Questionaire//
                    return View(controlviewmodel);
                }
            }

// Here is where the Model binder I am not able to understand why I am not able to get the list of QuestionaireMaster model which is a part of the ControlViewModel //

// Pls suggest If  something is architecturally wrong or need to do a work around//

    [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Index(ControlViewModel sampleobject)
            {    

    // sample object is null, even I tried to get List<QuestionaireMasterModel> it was also null   //

    return View();
            }
```

**PartialView**

```
// Bound to List of Controls //

    @model IEnumerable<CDCPortal.Models.QuestionaireControlMasterModel>

    <table>

        @foreach (CDCPortal.Models.QuestionaireControlMasterModel DynamicModel in Model)
        {
            switch (DynamicModel.ControlType.ToLower())
            {
                case "textbox":
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @DynamicModel.ControlLabel
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="@DynamicModel.ControlName" id="@DynamicModel.ControlId" value="@DynamicModel.ControlValue" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    break;
               }
          }
```

**View**

```
// View bound to Viewmodel //

    @model CDCPortal.Models.ControlViewModel

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div>
// Using the Partial View here to render up controls//

            @Html.Partial("_ControlPartial", Model.ListofControls)
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" name="SubmitButton" value="Submit" />
        </div>

    }
```

Comment: Because (1) your using a partial to generate the collection (2) because you use a `foreach` loop in the partial to generated the form controls. Look at the html for the controls your generating. All you have are multiple duplcate `name` attributes (which wont bind to a collection) and muttiple duplicate `id` attributes (invalid html). You need to use a custom `EditorTemplate` for type of `QuestionaireControlMasterModel` and in the main view just `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ListofControls)`

Comment: Your html should look like `<input name="ListofControls[0].Id" ../>` and `<input name="ListofControls[1].Id" ../>` etc.

Comment: @Html.Editorfor(m=>m.ListofControls, "Here I would have to pass in the Viewmodel object") , In Editor Template it would be bound to the QuestionaireMaster model am I right. Same thing is what I do in partial view , whats the difference

Comment: My intention is to learn so pls help

Comment: Whats the difference - look at the html your generating!!

Comment: Sorry to be harsh, but the answer to _" tell me whats wrong"_ is everything. You don't have values in a database or even in a model for things like ControlType, ControlName, ControlValue etc. Best guess from what you have shown is your creating some kind of questionnaire when the answers may be text, yes/no or multiple choice. If that's the case, delete everything and start again.

Comment: I have values in db for everything like controlname, id etc , from there only the value is given for <input type="" id="value from db"> , and pls see that the QuestionaireControl model is replica of db to have all values, I am trying to prepare a List of QuestionaireControlModel place it in a view model and send it to View

Comment: Pls say still my approach is wrong

Comment: Read my last comment - your model (and certainly not the database) should not know anything about how its values are rendered. You `Questions` table should contain (say) `int ID`, `int Questionnaire` (FK to the `Questionnaire` table), `varchar Name` and `varchar Type` where type is an enum value (say "text", "yes/no", "multiplechoice").

Comment: great got you , so that I check whether its text and then I generate a control for the same . Then my question arises how will I name the individual controls uniquely is this the way var i=0{ foreach<input type="text" id=ListControlname[i] } . Then I should place these in Editor Template this control generation part. So that on post I get the ViewModel which contains the List<Controls>

Comment: You need to start with your view models. You might have `TextAnswerVM`, `YesNoAnswerVM` and `MultipleChoiceVM`. Each would contain properties for the`QuestionID` and `QuestionText`. The `TextAnswerVM` would contain `string Answer` while the `YesNoAnswerVM` would contain `bool Answer` The main view model would contain properties `List<TextAnswerVM> TextAnswers`, `List<YesNoAnswerVM> YesNoAnswers` etc. You then use `for` loops (or custom `EditorTemplates` for each `XXAnswerVM` in the main view.

Comment: Thanks Stephen got the complete picture, :)